# Search NSArray of NSDictionary (which contains NSArray of NSDictionary, repeatedly)

Tags: ios, search, tree, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a data-structure (in plist) that looks something like this:

[image]

What i have here is an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`. Each `NSDictionary` has two keys:

```
Title
Link (recursive)
```

This forms a tree like structure, with variable length branches i.e. some branches can die at level 0, and some can be as large as level 3 or more.

I'm showing this structure in `UITableView` (with a little help from `UINavigationController`). This was easy enough.

> Note: On tapping the Leaf Node
>   (represented by `NSDictionary` object
>   with *Nil* or *Zero* as "Link"), an
>   event is triggered i.e. Model window
>   appears with some information.

Now, i need to add Search support.

Search bar will appear above `UITabeView` (for Level 0). I need to come-up with a way to search this tree like structure, and then show the results using `UISearchDisplayController`, and then allow users to navigate the results as well.

> How?... is where i'm a little stuck
>   and need some advise.

The search has to be quick, because we want *search as you type*.

p.s. I've thought of translating this data structure to CoreData, and it's still lurking in my mind. If you think it can help in this case, please advise.

---

Edit:
Here's my current solution, which is working (by the way):

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController methods 

- (void)searchBarResultsListButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [self filterCategoriesForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[controller.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    [self filterCategoriesForSearchText:[controller.searchBar text]
                               scope:[controller.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]];

    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController helper methods

- (void)filterCategoriesForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSInteger)scope {
    self.filteredCategories = [self filterCategoriesInArray:_categories forSearchText:searchText];

    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:KEY_DICTIONARY_TITLE ascending:YES] autorelease];
    [self.filteredCategories sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor, nil]];
}

- (NSMutableArray *)filterCategoriesInArray:(NSArray *)array forSearchText:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *filteredResults = nil;

    // Apply filter to array
    // For some weird reason this is not working. Any guesses? [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ CONTAINS[cd] %@", KEY_DICTIONARY_TITLE, searchText];
    NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchText];
    filteredResults = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];

    // Store the filtered results (1)
    if ((filteredResults != nil) && ([filteredResults count] > 0)) {
        [resultArray addObjectsFromArray:filteredResults];
    }

    // Loop on related records to find the matching results
    for (NSDictionary *dictionayObject in array) {
        NSArray *innerCategories = [dictionayObject objectForKey:KEY_DICTIONARY_LINK];

        if ((innerCategories != nil) && ([innerCategories count] > 0)) {
            filteredResults = [self filterCategoriesInArray:innerCategories forSearchText:searchText];

            // Store the filtered results (2)
            if ((filteredResults != nil) && ([filteredResults count] > 0)) {
                [resultArray addObjectsFromArray:filteredResults];
            }
        }
    }

    return resultArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data *would* be able to perform the search in the data store pretty efficiently, and would scale the search to more levels efficiently. Also, if you use [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the TableView it would almost certainly be more memory efficient - the worst case would only have one level array loaded at any given time. And the best case is considerably better, as it would only have [faulted](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html) a few objects into the array. HTH